How can you force a React component to re-render without updating its state or props?
how to re-render the component without changing the react state or props
I've attempted the following in a functional component:
1.Using the useState hook and updating state with the same value
2.Creating a new object as a prop to try to trigger a re-render
3.Using useReducer with a dummy state update
None of these methods feel like the right approach, and some seem to go against React's principles.
PS: this is for research purpose , don't have current scenario for this one but you can find one for general use-case
Imagine a component that relies on window.innerWidth for responsive behavior, but doesn't store this value in state. If the window is resized, the component won't automatically re-render to adjust its layout.

Why do you need to rerender component when the component state is not changing?

If the props or states are not updating or changing then re-rendering the component makes no sense. If there is a specific case then please mention the complete scenario for a better understanding of the problem.

This question is similar to: Can you force a React component to rerender without calling setState?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Nikhil Imagine a component that relies on window.innerWidth for responsive behavior, but doesn't store this value in state. If the window is resized, the component won't automatically re-render to adjust its layout.

Then that's an X/Y question. The component should observe the window width; there are pre-made hooks for that.
